# Editable area on landing page for site admins

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

My Rails app has a landing page for visitors with welcome/contact info.

At the moment, this info/html lies in a template.

I want to make it editable for the admins of the application.

What options do I have to accomplish this? Should I create a model with a `first_page` attribute where I store the html submitted by the admins in a form? Or is there any other way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need some kind of content management system (CMS).  There are lots of ready-made ones for Rails.  see http://codecall.net/2014/02/10/best-ruby-on-rails-content-management-systems-cms/

You could just write your own, but you'll end up writing functionality around editing the pages, and then the admins will ask for the ability to upload images etc, and you'll think "gah, wish i'd just used an off the shelf CMS".

Comment: True, but this is for a single page and a very small text area in that page. No images needed. So if there would be an easier way I would prefer that. but I'll look into a CMS otherwise.

Comment: In my experience, once users get something they want more. :)  If you're sure this is all you will ever want to do then make a new model (with controller & standard views) called ContentPage, and give it fields called "slug" which is unique, and "body".  Make the controller accessable by admins only.  Then on the info page you can say something like <%= ContentPage.find_by_slug("info").body %>.  Then, later, when they say "Hey, Numbers, how do I upload an image to use on the info page?", you can say "gah, wish i'd just used an off the shelf CMS".  ;-)